# Asp.Net MVC Getting Display Names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, attributes

I am trying to get Display Name attributes in a model and display them in a loop. I am able to get Property name but unable to pull displayName attributes. Any help on logic would be highly appreciated. I tried debugging, adding watch to Model.GetType() and could not trace out attributes part.

```
 @foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                <li>
                    <div>
                        @propertyInfo.Name
                    </div>
                </li>   
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => @propertyInfo.Name)
```